# some browser problems on my code

Tags: internet-explorer-6

my [website](http://www.terranartworks.com/testsite/tsv1/index.html),  has some issues acting different for different browsers.

1. the red panel appearing under the grey buttons on bottom,seems only ff,not other browsers.
2. when user clicks one of grey buttons on the bottom,red panel should start under the white panel.but it starts a little bit of its left side.
3. the white panel on the left side on islerimiz.html(which user clicks middle button on bottom) page should be blurred.i added script for this but it is not doing blurring thing.the same script is on the iletisim.html(which user clicks rightest button on bottom) page and it is working truly.

**ie6 errors:**

1. the red point seems as a rectangle.
2. red panel script is not working.
3. the background of page and the logo's background should be the same but they seems different
4. the blurred panel on islerimiz.html page is not appearing at all.the bottom buttons seems true but the active button's color should be black but it seems grey too.besides little pictures should appear when mouse hover on the grey buttons,appears on open position.
5. the blurred panel on iletisim.html is not appearing.the pictures on the blured panel appears with shadows and shape is rectangle.also the links on that pictures is not clickable.

how can i solve this problems with css.if i couldn't solve with css,i can try jquery but my first choice is css.i have more than one javascript library on index page.but if i remove one of them,some scripts is not working.

Answer (score 0):

almost all of those issues are because you are using pngs. switch them to gifs. apply them in a style sheet wrapped in conditional comments, at least for ie6, and a percentage of that list will go away. your selectivizrCSSForIEselectivizr.js is also targeting greater than ie6. i'm not sure what the red panel script exactly is, but i see you are adding webm file for ie...idk 100%, but i'll say it doesn't support that format either. convert it to media type that ie6 likes, and again, only serve this up in the ie6 conditional comments